# Android Studio: Send Images to Whatsapp

Tags: android-studio, integration, whatsapp

Am working on a project named Bulk Messages for Whatsapp. Faced some problem on it. I want to send Images to Whatsapp through my application. Here is the code:

```
Send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String MobileNumber = edt_txt_mobile.getText().toString();
                    String Message = edt_txt_message.getText().toString();

                    boolean installed = appInstalledOrNot("com.whatsapp");

                    if (installed) {
                        for(int i=0; i<MobileNumbersList.size(); i++) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + "+92" + 
                            MobileNumbersList.get(i) + "&text=" + Message));
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + "+92" + 
                            MobileNumbersList.get(i) + "&image=" + imageEncoded));
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        MobileNumbersList.clear();
                        edt_txt_mobile.setText("");
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Whatsapp not Installed in your Contact", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });    
    }
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: That Line is Not Working: {intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + "+92" + 
                            MobileNumbersList.get(i) + "&image=" + imageEncoded));}

Comment: Can you post in your question the error that you are getting from the logcat? That way it is easier for us to help you solve the problem :)

Comment: I get the Image Path from the Gallery in imageEncoded string variable. Intent jump into Whatsapp and doesnot load image

Comment: you can use ```Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);``` and ```intent.setType("text/plain");```

Comment: that does not work

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, message is a String that adds text to the picture

```
private void sendWhatsappPictureChooseContact(Bitmap bitmap, String message) {
        Uri uri = getmageToShare(bitmap);
        // Create send intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        // putting uri of image to be shared
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        // adding text to share
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        // setting type to image
        intent.setType("image/*");
        // Whatsapp package name so intent can identify which app to open
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        // Start activity
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```